# Setting height of iframe via media queries

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to have this embed load a iframe of 200px and for mobile screens load a height of 140px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      .iframe {
        height:140px;
      }
  }
</style>

  <body style="margin:0px">

  <iframe width="100%" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FtveSk1N7Uo?enablejsapi=1&origin=http://domain.com&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

This isn't working though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because inline styles (`height="200"` on the iframe) take precedence over any other styles. Also, your selector won't match your markup - it should be `iframe` (the element) not `.iframe` (a class).

Try taking the `height=200` off of the iframe, and putting it before your media query in your styles:

```
iframe {
  height: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  iframe {
    height:140px;
  }
```

}

On a side note, it's generally better to use `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`. The former will apply your small styles to a small laptop or desktop browser window; the latter won't.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/GcaMYbu1lEBJqL1OQnL2?p=preview

It should be iframe not .iframe. '.' is the selector for classes and iframe here is not a class but html element and thus should be mentioned with just the element name.

```
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
      iframe {
        height:140px;
      }
  }
```